# How to limit workers doing tasks in a specific queue? [Celery][Python]

Tags: python, concurrency, task, celery

For python celery.

I have 2 queues (say q1 and q2) and several tasks for them.

Some memory-consuming tasks will be drop into q2 and others to q1. And I don't want 2 q2 tasks (memory consuming tasks) executing at the same time. Can I leave some limitations for them to prevent 2 or more workers doing q2 tasks at the same time? Like set concurrency for each queue? How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `asyncio`. This package can help you define and manage your concurrent tasks as you wish.